# Backups fail to copy over the network

Tags: sql-server, backup

We have a backup process set to copy files over to a different network. Occasionally we lose internet connection and then one of the backups files will fail to copy over. This becomes a bigger issue for larger files as they take much longer to copy over and if it needs to be copied again we need to wait a few hours. Our proposed solution is to split the backups across multiple files so that when it fails we only lose a smaller file.

Is there any other/better solutions to handle this type of issue?

Comment: what is the error message you get on SQL server? and have you checked OS and firewall logs?

Comment: Strongly recommend something like `rsync` on Windows for example Robocopy. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy

Answer (score 1):

if you backup to multiple files the backup will normally run faster - so I think this is a win win suggestion. If you do the file copy with something like robocopy then there is retry built in.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately you need to look for a stable network/internet connection, because any alternative solution that you may think of (splitting backup into small files, having retry options from copy tool) would eventually depend on the network/internet.

However, splitting backup files and compress them locally (perhaps using [7-zip](https://www.7-zip.org/)) prior to copy, can reduce the time of copy, so less chances of failure, but not complete solution!

Comment: Integrated backup compression has been in the standard edition since SQL 2008R2, this would be the preferred method rather than using a second tool to compress.

Comment: @JonathanFite, I agree, but we can still yield some storage space (around 10%) by doing compression with 7-zip though backup files are compressed (`BACKUP ... WITH COMPRESSION`), might not be logical taking CPU overhead into consideration, but it help for OP scenario.

Comment: I've never found using SQL compression (which is optimized for speed) to have any appreciable impact on the cpu.  And compressing natively means fewer bytes written which usually means shorter time spent taking the backup (and thus holding the log).  A third party tool doing the compression would need to be run from a different server to avoid cpu impact on the SQL server, plus now you have to pickup and write the bytes again.  For the assumed 10% storage savings over native compression, that's a lot of time and scheduling effort.  Plus lower restore effort.

Comment: @JonathanFite, I mean, CPU overhead when we use third-party tool, not with native compression :-)